# htaccess redirect avoid specific domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(domaintoavoid1|domaintoavoid)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(domaintoavoid1|domaintoavoid2)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I currently have this www/https redirection, but I have certain domains on which I didn't set up a SSL certificate and I'd like to be able to bypass the redirect entirely. It isn't currently working though, domaintoavoid.com and www.domaintoavoid.com still get redirected to https.

Comment: `https%1` -- Why do you have the `%1` there? That looks like it would be capturing from `(www\.)`.

Comment: I don't think the %1 is necessary. But how would it capture (www\.) as the condition is a negation?

Comment: seems like you have a whole lot of redundant stuff going on there. Do you want to have www or not on your URL's when you redirect to https? and that backreference is not helping,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it like this in separate rules

```
# skip these domains from https/www rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(?:domaintoavoid1|domaintoavoid)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to clean your browser cache before testing this.